# Define keys based on values in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Is something like this possible in an elegant way?

db:

```
{
  type: "a",
  foo: [1, 2, 3],
},
{
  type: "b",
  foo: [9, 4, 5],
}
```

output:

```
{
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: [9, 4, 5],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $arrayToObject aggregation operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$group:{_id:null, newArray: {$push:{k:"$type", v:"$foo"}}}},
   {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:{$arrayToObject:"$newArray"}}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p8Fdl_-RhZu)

Comment: Awesome, arrayToObject is exactly what I was looking for!